# Why is the switch drawn like this (NRST, STM32)?

Tags: switches, stm32, nrst

The below part of a circuit is from the AN2586 Reference design for an STM32F1:

https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00164185-getting-started-with-stm32f10xxx-hardware-development-stmicroelectronics.pdf

RESET goes to the NRST pin of an STM32, and the left clipped line towards a JTAG connector.

B1 is a button, but what is the advantage of having the lines near 3 and 4? What is the difference with a simple 2 pin button?

[image]

Comment: it is a simple two pin button

Comment: @JYelton Yes it does, but it didn't show up when I asked my question.

Comment: Understandably, I knew I'd seen a similar question but damned if I could find it without checking my activity history. It's not well-worded for "tactile pushbutton" related searches. (But linking it here helps!)

Comment: @JYelton normally I search first (either google or directly here, Google mostly points towards StackExchange anyway). But it mainly depends on the title if it can be found (same for StackExchange search I think).

Comment: This question got closed during the time I was preparing an answer so I posted the answer on the duplicate question instead. Here is the link: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/501013/12135

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many pcb mount push buttons are 4 pin, mostly for mechanical stability (as far as I'm aware). They are often internally connected like this (i.e. the pins on each of the two sides are connected together). Since you have the pins anyway, you might as well connect them together externally as well just in case you want to use a different switch where they aren't connected together internally.

[image]

Comment: Ok clear ... so I can easily change it for an SMT 2 pin button.

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation